# Finding specific PNG images and renaming them

Tags: find, directory, mv

I have to find multiple files named `logo.png` in different subdirectories, and change their names to `oldlogo.png`, how do I do that?

I already have the beginning, finding the file (each `logo.png` file is 56431 bytes), but I don't know how to move them to another file, within the same subdirectory.

This is what I have for finding the files:

```
find -name logo.png -size 56431c
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `find` command finds exactly the files that you want to rename, you may rename these by calling `mv` from `find` using `-execdir` like so:

```bsh
find . -name logo.png -size 56431c -execdir mv {} oldlogo.png \;
```

The `-execdir` predicate is non-standard but often implemented.  It executes the given utility in the directory where the name was found, with `{}` replaced by the name of the file (GNU `find` will prepend `./` to the filename, while other `find` implementations might not do that).  In the command above, we use this fact to rename the `logo.png` file into `oldlogo.png` without specifying directory paths.

Using standard `find`, you may want to do it like this instead:

```bsh
find . -name logo.png -size 56431c -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        mv "$pathname" "${pathname%/*}/oldlogo.png"
    done' sh {} +
```

The above will call `sh -c` with batches pathnames of found files.  The in-line script will iterate over the given batch of pathnames and renames each one into `oldlogo.png` in the same directory as where `find` found it.  The parameter substitution `${pathname%/*}` will remove the last `/` and everything after it from the value of `$pathname` (so that it acts like `dirname "$pathname"` in that it returns the directory part of the pathname).